# Git merge using Github Desktop - Changes not getting merged

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I have a branch development1 branched from master and development2 branched from development1. I wanted all changes I made in development2 in development1 and when I tried merging development2 to development1 branch, I am not able to get the changes which I already have in development1 branch but I have only the changes made in development2 branch. The files already in development1 are overwritten by development2 branch. I use Github Desktop for merging. Can someone tell me what is wrong here and how to solve this? I've already spent a full day trying to sort this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a pull request from branch 2 to branch1? Upload your changes to remote, and then from the web do the pull request.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.